# python function yields tuple and only one element is wanted

Tags: python, tuples, generator, yield

I have a function

```
def f():
    # whatever
    yield (a,b)
```

Now I would like to collect all the `a` but not `b`. Also I want the result `aa` to be a list instead of iterator. Right now I use

```
aa, _ = zip(*f())
```

Is this the best one can do in terms of space/time efficiency?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`zip(*seq)` has to ingest the whole generator, before it can output the columns. This is not efficient.

Just stick to a list comprehension. You could use tuple assignment:

```
aa = [a for a, _ in f()]
```

or use indexing:

```
aa = [tup[0] for tup in f()]
```

If you don't *have* to have all values available for random access or other operations that must have a list, you can use a generator expression to maintain the memory efficiency:

```
aa = (a for a, _ in f())
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a list comprehension that grabs the first returned item

```
aa = [result[0] for result in f()]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can not make it yield only one element of the tuple, without modifying `f`.  However, you can easily chain generators, for example with a generator expression:

```
just_a_please = (a for a,b in f())
```

To consume all the a's in one hit, you should prefer a list comprehension:

```
all_a = [a for a,b in f()]
```

If you only want one of them, there is `next`:

```
give_me_an_a, _b = next(f())
```

Answer (score 1):

simple, you can use list comprehension to get a list with the whole thing

```
aa = [ a for a,_ in f() ]
```

Answer (score 0):

For a solution using the `operator` module:

```
from operator import itemgetter
get_first = itemgetter(0)
aa = [get_first(x) for x in f()]
```

*Edit: I originally stated "for an efficient solution using the `operator` module," but I cannot find any evidence that it is any more efficient than the standard list comprehension approach.*

**Some anecdotal `%timeit` observations:**

```
def f():
    for i in xrange(0, 10000):
        yield (i, i ** i)

def operator_way():
    return [get_first(x) for x in f()]

def tuple_unpack_way():
    return [a for a, _ in f()]

def indexing_way():
    return [a[0] for a in f()]

def map_way():
    return map(get_first, f())
```

---

```
%timeit operator_way() # 100 loops, best of 3: 9.25 ms per loop
```

---

```
%timeit tuple_unpack_way() # 100 loops, best of 3: 9.28 ms per loop
```

---

```
%timeit indexing_way() # 100 loops, best of 3: 9.17 ms per loop
```

---

```
%timeit map_way() # 100 loops, best of 3: 9.07 ms per loop
```

### They seem more or less equivalent. Map may be slightly more efficient.

Comment: You might test: `[x[0] for x in f()]` too.

Comment: @DanD. Good call. Added a test for that too.